# Show that the only bi-lateral ideal of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is $\{0\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, ideals

Show that the only bi-lateral ideal of $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ is $\{0\}$. I can see that $\{0\}$ is a bi-lateral (two-sided) ideal but, I cannot show that it is the ONLY one because even if I tried applying left and right actions to an arbitrary matrix, it seems this wouldn't work. Any feedback would be great.

Comment: Consider the action of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ on $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ by conjugation.

Comment: @anomaly If I consider that, it's just something like $AMA^{-1}$ and then we have things like $A(M+N)A^{-1}=AMA^{-1}+ANA^{-1}$ but, it's still hard to see why only $M=0$ fits the bill..

Comment: Well, there's also $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ itself.

Comment: @NoodleNami Feedback: had your question not been a duplicate, it would have been closed for quality issues. Please [see this advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/29335) for improving questions, and also try to exercise using the site's search engine.